# How to count values of table column from a certain row in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I want to return the sum of the total value of a table column starting from a particular row.

In the screenshot below, I want to start from row number 2 till the last row. How can this be achieved in Laravel?

[image: Screenshot of my table]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: \DB::table('table_name')->where('id', '>', '2')->sum('followers');

Comment: Thanks @Khan. That does the trick!

Comment: I was doing it like this before. $user = User::find(Auth::id());
            $username = $user->username;
            $downline = DB::table('level_one_models')
                ->where('user_username', $username)->sum('followers');